# Creating a new set of dataframes from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataset with a parameter of location. There are approximately 75 locations. Each location can have sub-locations. I needed to make plots for each location, so I broke the dataset into a dictionary of dataframes and worked on each value within the dictionary.

Now I need to breakdown each value in the dictionary (the dataset belonging to the location) into datasets by sublocation. So if a location has 3 sublocation, I need 3 new dataframes.

Using the following posts:
[PANDAS split dataframe to multiple by unique values rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769453/pandas-split-dataframe-to-multiple-by-unique-values-rows)

[Loop through a dictionary of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55388844/loop-through-a-dictionary-of-dataframes)

```
f = '..../demo_copy.csv'
d = pd.DataFrame()
d= pd.read_csv(f)
dfs = dict(tuple(d.groupby('location')))
for key, value in dfs.items():
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=False)
    sns.catplot(data = value,
    x='ethnic',
    kind = 'count',
    palette = 'cubehelix',
    label = 'Ethnicity',
    ax=ax1)
    #plt.savefig("{0}.pdf".format(key), bbox_inches = 'tight')
for key, value in dfs.items():
    dfs2 = dict(tuple(value.groupby('site')))
```

When I look at the length of dfs2, I noticed that it only has 3 datasets. I know there are nearly 300 sublocations, so I need dfs2 to have key name of sublocation and value of all rows of 'd' with corresponding location and sublocation

EDIT: I am attaching some sample data
[Sample Data. In the real data (it's sensitive can't post it) there are over 70locations and 300 sublocations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2YES.png)

the dictionary dfs has key M1 value: (all rows with location M1)

now I need dfs2 with key 21M1 value: (all rows with sublocation 21M1)
They should still be grouped by the location, which is why I was thinking about a 'sub dictionary'
EDIT2: Following the advice of @Joe I used the fact that I can access each location using the dictionary I have. Using my original data I can make a list of unique sublocation values. Then use a loop to go through each dict value, and make a tmp dataframe where the sublocation matches some value in the unique list. I can use the temp dataframe to do my stats. I am adding the code too. Any chance this maybe flawed?

```
for i in dfs.values():
    for j in unique_list:
        try:
            tmp = i[i['sublocation']==j]
            ax1 = sns.countplot(y='ethnic_cde', data=tmp, orient='h', palette ='colorblind');
            sns.despine();
            ax1.set(xlabel='Count', ylabel='Ethnicity by Code');
            plt.savefig("{0}.pdf".format(j), bbox_inches = 'tight')
        except:
            pass
```

EDIT 3: I am stuck with one last thing. I can't get the file to save in the proper directory. I made a new dictionary where key:values are subloc:d[d['subloc']== X]

```
for key, value in dfss.items():
    a = str(value['location']);
    try:

        fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3);
        tmppath = 'path';
        sns.countplot(y='ethnic_cde', data=value, orient='h', palette ='colorblind', ax=axs[0]);
        sns.countplot(y='ProgramRatio', data=value,orient='v', palette ='colorblind',ax=axs[1]);
        sns.countplot(y='sublocation', data = value, ax=axs[2]);
        plt.tight_layout();
        plt.savefig(tmppath+a+'/{0}_{1}.pdf'.format(a,key), bbox_inches = 'tight');
        plt.clf();
        #plt.show()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Include a snippet of the data you are working with

Comment: @Joe added some sample data

Comment: I see, you need to plot per location and per sub location? Why not filter the dataframe instead, first by `'location'` and the resulting filtered df will be filtered by `'sublocation'`? I think that is faster than doing operations on iterables.

Comment: @Joe I had considered this, the thing is I need to go and make graphs for each filter, furthermore each set of graphs needs to be saved as a pdf. I wasn't exactly sure how to go about this using a loop. Maybe the apply method? What is good is that I have a dictionary which is split by location. That's half the job, now I can access each dict. value and try and split into the various sublocation groups.

EDIT: And yes, the code is a bit slow. Takes like 30 seconds, but when I consider I have nearly 20K rows and I'm plotting a few different columns, it's a small price to pay.

Comment: Loop on each value of the column you need the value for the filter with. Then create the dataframes you need by that filter. Then store it in a list, then finally loop through that list of dataframes you have to do the plotting and any other computation you need?

Comment: Are you sure those last two lines are what you want? You are replacing `dfs2` in every iteration so it will end up being only computed using the last dataframe in `dfs`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @tomjn that is not what I want, essentially the dfs2 should have nearly 350 (one dataframe for each subloc. what i was aiming to do there was go through each item in dfs, group it by subloc and add each one into a new dict

Comment: @Joe I tried what you suggested, I think Im closer to what I needed. I threw in the error exception because some missing values in the sublocations.

Comment: I'll post an answer to what I suggested. Glad to have helped man.

Comment: @Joe thanks a lot. My last thing is trying to save it in the right directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Joe @tomjn
Here's what I ended up doing:

I take my two original dictionaries, create a third one so that the keys are locations and the value is a list of sublocations.

```
dfs = dict(tuple(d.groupby('location')));
dfss = dict(tuple(d.groupby('sublocation')));
dd = {}
for key, value in dfs.items():
    a = []
    dee={}
    for i in value['sublocation']:
        if i in a:
            pass
        else:
            a.append(str(i))
    dee = {key:a}
    dd.update(dee)
for key, value in dfss.items(): 
    try:
        for k, v in dd.items():
            if key in v:
                dur=str(k)
        else:
             pass

         #CODE FOR PLOTS
         #SAVE PLOT           
   except:
         #SAVE PLOT
         pass
```

I needed this because I want to make a bunch of plots and eventually I do as follows I put the actual

```
plt.savefig("path.pdf".format(dur,dur,key), bbox_inches = 'tight')
```